How to modify PowerShell selected MenuComplete text color only on the input line
I'm aware here that one solution for this problem has been given. But the following code:
$colors = @{
   "Selection" = "$([char]0x1b)[38;2;0;0;0;48;2;178;255;102m"
}

Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors $colors

Sets the color of the selected text to be the same in both the input line and the interactive menu. What I want is to differentiate the two like the following:

How do I achieve that? (I'm using PowerShell 7.4.6)

With  Get-PSReadLineOption you can check your color options.
With Set-PsReadLineOption -Colors @{Command = "'e[93m" }, for example, you can set color of command parameter.
To save it in a permanent way, you must add set command into your profile:
notepad $PROFILE

This is the list of color you can change:

Now you have only to edit as you prefer 

But as you can see, there is no option there that would differentiate the color of the selected text in the input line and the interactive menu. Like if I change the SelectionColor, it would change both instead of one of them.
